# onChange event not rendering with Boostrap using React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, rendering

I am trying to display a grid of input forms. When the use updates the input form with a new price, the Interface priceEntered is updated with the user inputs (this value will be used later on). However, every-time I try to write anything in the input, nothing happens and it seems it is rendering without letting me update the value. Any idea of what I am missing?

````
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';


interface IAlbum {
  id: number,
  title: string,
  artist: string,
  price: number,
}

interface IAlbumState {
  priceEntered: number;
}

const INITIAL_STATE_ALB: IAlbumState = {
  priceEntered: 0,
}

class App extends React.Component<unknown, IAlbumState> {

  public state: IAlbumState = {
    ...INITIAL_STATE_ALB,
  };

 
  public handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ priceEntered: Number(e.target.value) });
    // item.price = Number(e.target.value);
    // console.log("price",item.price);
  }


  public render = () => {

    let albums : IAlbum[] = [];

    albums = [
        {
          id: 0,
          title: 'Album One',
          artist: 'Alex',
          price: 12
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Album Two',
          artist: 'Percy',
          price: 10
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Album Three',
          artist: 'Kevin',
          price: 120
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Album Four',
          artist: 'John',
          price: 0
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'Album Five',
          artist: 'Stacy',
          price: 1200
        }
      ]


    const GridSystem = ({ colCount, children, md } : {colCount:number, children:any, md:number}) => {
            
      const rowCount = Math.floor(children.length / colCount) + 1

      // Index is needed to keep track of the current element that we are one.
      let index = 0

      // This is the driver function for building the grid system.
      const buildGrid = () => {
        return (
          renderRows()
          )
      }

      // Returns For example, we can have a row with 2 columns inside it.
      const renderRows = () => {
      const rows = []
            
      for(let row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        rows.push(
          <Row key={row} className='Row row-flex'>
            {
              renderCols()
            }
          </Row>
          )
        }            
        return rows
      }

      // Returns an array of columns with the children inside.
      const renderCols = () => {
      const cols = []
        
      // If you want to add more bootstrap breakpoints you can pass them as props here.
      for(let col = 0; col < colCount; col++) {
        if(index < children.length) {
          cols.push(
            <Col key={col} className='Col' md={md}>
              {children[index]}
            </Col>
          )
          index++
        }
      }        
      return cols
    }

      return (
        <Container className='Container'>
          { buildGrid() }
        </Container>
      );
    };

    const Item = (props: any) => {

      const { item } = props

      return (
        <div className='product product-inner content'>
          <div className="w-75 p-3 block-center">
            <div className="input-group mb-3">            
              <span className="input-group-text">Price </span>  
              <input type='text' className="form-control" defaultValue={ item.price ?? 0 } onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    
    return (     
      <div>
        <GridSystem colCount={2} md={6}>
          { albums.map(item => <Item key={item.id} item={item} />) }
        </GridSystem>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
}

export default App;```
````

Comment: You're declaring components within the render. This means it get's unmounted and re-mounted every single render. This will lead to bugs.

Comment: Also, while the above is definitely true, your current issue may also be related to using `defaultValue` instead of `value` for your inputs. `defaultValue` only get's used on the initial render.

Comment: Thanks. I played with *value/initialValue* but the issue does not seem to come from there. So I moved both components ( *Item* and *GridSystem*) outside of the render function (and outside of the *App* class function). However, this will require the Item component to explicitly take another input (this in my case), as it is used inside the code. Could that lead to potential issues?